# Compute the distances between two nodes and their lowest common ancestor (LCA)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to compute the distance that separate two nodes A and B with their lowest common ancestor in a graph. I use the followinf function to find LCA:

```
match p1 = (A:Category {idCat: "Main_topic") -[*0..]-> (common:Category) <-[*0..]- (B:Category {idCat: "Heat_transfer"}) 
return common, p1
```

Is there any function in Neo4j that allows to return the respective distance between d(A,common) and d(B, common).

Thank you fo your help

Comment: What do you mean by "lowest common ancestor"? Your query returns *every possible* `common` node (potentially multiple times).

Comment: LCA is an ancestor node shared between A and B
Example: 
A->W->C->D . B->k->C->D. LCA between A and B is C (D also is a common parent but it's not the lowest).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the `lowest common ancestor` correctly, this comes down to finding the shortest path between `A` and `B` with at least one node in between. That you can do using this query. Here the condition that the length of `p` is larger than 1 forces at least one node between the two. Below example uses the [IMDB toy database](http://example-data.neo4j.org/3.0-datasets/cineasts.tgz) and returns the movie Avatar.

```
match p=shortestPath((n:Person {name:'Zoe Saldana'})-[r*1..15]-(n1:Person {name:'James Cameron'})) where length(p) > 1 return nodes(p)[1]
```

Basically you can choose any element from the nodes in the path, except the first and last one (since those will be `A` and `B`)